# trying to escape certain values in a file using php?

Tags: php

i have this file that i want to open, a csv file, and i want to escape the 1st and 4th value for each line of data, a data record represented by `$i`.

when i say data record i mean each data that is split by a comma i.e.

data1, data2, data3, data4 .... etc.

this is my solution so far:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($file_opener, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
          $num = count($data);

              for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) {
                // for each 2nd and 3rd value push to array
                 array_push($Ages, $data[$i]);
               // if 1st and fourth value do nothing.
              }
```

i hope this is not confusing, if you need clarification let me know, and i did check the php docs, i was trying to use the array_chunk and map methods, but i don't know how to use them in this instance. thanks

Comment: i was also thinking to use modulus , to see the remainders, but im not sure if its the most efficient way, another way was to have an $row array and check against that?

Comment: "escape" means "discard"? I.e. if the input is `1,2,3,4,5,6` the resulting array would be `array(2,3,5,6)`?

Comment: if the input was `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` then array would be `array(2,3,6,7);`

Comment: can you give an example of the input file with some lines and an example fo your desired output array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure what you're trying to achieve, but this script removes *each* 1st and 4th element from each 4-column group in a record.

```
<?php
while( false!==($record=getNextRow()) ) {
    foreach($record as $k=>$v) {
        $rpos = $k % 4;
        if ( 0==$rpos || 3==$rpos ) {
            unset($record[$k]);
        }
    }
    echo join(', ', $record), "\n";
}

function getNextRow() {
    // just boilerplate to make it a self-contained example
    // this would be plain fgetcsv in yor case
    static $source = array('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8', 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l', 'I,II,III,IV,V,VI,VII,VIII','IX');
    list(,$r) = each($source);
    return $r ? str_getcsv($r) : false;
}
```

prints

```
2, 3, 6, 7
b, c, f, g, j, k
II, III, VI, VII
```

Comment: congrats for guessing this specs ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($file_opener, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);

    for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) {
        if($i == 1 || $i == 2) {
            array_push($Ages, $data[$i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i can see what you doing, but i have 1000 records, so this will only work in the first line?

Comment: this works for every line, but keeps only the second and third value of each line.

Comment: As you said - `//for each 2nd and 3rd value push to array`

Answer (score 0):

i don't get, if you want `$Ages` to be one-dimensional or multi-dimensional.

in case of **one-dimensional** and 
if the input was:

```
32, 554, 64, 34, 24, 43, 76
43, 322, 43, 543, 23, 54, 54
45, 34, 5654, 23, 43, 2, 5
```

this code would fill `$Ages`:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($file_opener, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);

    for ($i=1; $i < $num; $i++) {
        if($i == 3) {
            continue;
        }
        array_push($Ages, $data[$i]);
    }

}
```

and `$Ages` would look like:

```
array(554, 64, 34, 24, 43, 76, 
    322, 43, 23, 54, 54, 
    34, 5654, 43, 2, 5);
```

in case of **multi-dimensional** and 
if the input was the same, this code:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($file_opener, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);

    unset(data[0]);
    unset(data[3]);

    array_push($Ages, $data);

}
```

would `$Ages` to look like:

```
array(
    (554, 64, 34, 24, 43, 76), 
    (322, 43, 23, 54, 54), 
    (34, 5654, 43, 2, 5)
);
```